# I am trying to get rid of the main scrollbar, is there a easy way to do this

Tags: css, html

I am able to do it by using javascript to resize the side nav but is there a css way to do it.

http://plnkr.co/edit/u992x6jmngt4ki4wePMf?p=preview

```
.leftnav {
  position:relative;
 overflow:scroll;
 height:100%;
 width:250px;
}


.topnav {
/*/position:absolute;*/
 overflow:hidden;
 height:100px ;
 width:100%;
 border: solid  green  3px;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
         box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand you... do you want to remove the sidebar scroll?? Then why do you use `overflow:scroll;` in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. You should make sure the 2 elements are not higher then the viewport.

Your leftnav is already 100% high. So the topnav makes the window scrollable. If you don't want this you should make sure that the two are not higher than 100%.

http://plnkr.co/edit/rVwAaihwaHvk19yLFdUb

make the leftnav the following height:

```
.leftnav {
    height: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```